# Preserving binary data in streams

Tags: c#, stream

Using C#, I was surprised how complicated it seemed to preserve binary info from a stream.  I'm trying to download a PNG datafile using the WebRequest class, but just transfering the resulting Stream to a file, without corrupting it was more verbose than I thought.  First, just using StreamReader and StreamWriter was no good as the ReadToEnd() function returns a string, which effectivly doubles the size of the PNG file (probably due to the UTF conversion)

So my question is,  do I really have to write all this code, or is there a cleaner way of doing it?

```
            Stream srBytes = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            // Write to file
            Stream swBytes = new FileStream("map(" + i.ToString() + ").png",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
            int count = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            do
            {
                count = srBytes.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                swBytes.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            while (count != 0);
            swBytes.Close();
```

Comment: You should never treat arbitrary byte streams as strings, though. Since they are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` is definitely a mistake, yes - because that's trying to load the file as text, which it's not.

Options:

- Use `WebClient.DownloadFile` as SLaks suggested
- In .NET 4, use [`Stream.CopyTo(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) to copy the data in much the same way as you've got here
- Otherwise, write your own utility method to do the copying, then you only need to do it once; you could even write this as an extension method, which means when you upgrade to .NET 4 you can just get rid of the utility method and use the built-in one with no change to the calling code:

  ```
  public static class StreamExtensions
  {
      public static void CopyTo(this Stream source, Stream destination)
      {
          if (source == null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
          }
          if (destination == null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException("destination");
          }
          byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
          int bytesRead;
          while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
          {
              destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Note that you should be using `using` statements for the web response, response stream and output stream in order to make sure they're always closed appropriately, like this:

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite("map(" + i + ").png"))
{
    responseStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call [`WebClient.DownloadFile(url, localPath)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx).

In .Net 4.0, you can simplify your current code by calling [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx).